# Automapper map class to abstract class

Tags: automapper

What I want to do is to get the lists (plural) in MugDTO record to the list (singular) in Mug class. They ar both exactly the same except for the "top level".

But I can't figure out how it should work. I've tried with custom value resolver and a Custom type converter but to no avail. Unfortunately I deleted the code for the converter and the resolver so I can't add them here.

This is what I started with:

```
CreateMap<MugDTO, Mug>().ForMember(x => x.MugItems, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Carriers));
```

On the front-end it looks like this:

```
public abstract class MugItem
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string BorderColor { get; set; }
}

public class Cartridge : MugItem
{

}

public class Carrier : MugItem
{

}
    
public class Mug
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MugItem> MugItems { get; set; }
}
```

On the back end it looks the same except for the mug has separate litst for the carrier and the cartridge.

```
public record MugDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<CarrierDTO> Carriers { get; set; }
    public List<CartridgeDTO> Cartridges { get; set; }
}
```

Error I get:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
MugDTO -> Mug
Test.Shared.Domain.MugDTO -> Test.Client.Domain.Mug

Type Map configuration:
MugDTO -> Mug
Test.Shared.Domain.MugDTO -> Test.Client.Domain.Mug

Destination Member:
MugItems

AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
MugDTO -> Mug
Test.Shared.Domain.MugDTO -> Test.Client.Domain.Mug

Type Map configuration:
MugDTO -> Mug
Test.Shared.Domain.MugDTO -> Test.Client.Domain.Mug

Destination Member:
MugItems

---> System.ArgumentException: Cannot create an instance of abstract type Test.Client.Domain.MugItem.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was that I needed two lines of code and to map and union the records inline.

```
CreateMap<MugItemDTO, MugItem>().IncludeAllDerived();

CreateMap<MugDTO, Mug>()
                .ForMember(dear => dear.MugItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(
                    (src, dest, member, context) => context.Mapper.Map<List<CarrierDTO>>(src.Carriers).Union<MugItemDTO>(context.Mapper.Map<List<CartridgeDTO>>(src.Cartridges))));
```

Comment: `Map` is useless. You just need `MapFrom` `Carriers` `Concat` `Cartridges`.

Comment: If I try that I get IEnumerable<CarrierDTO> does not contian a defenition for Concat and the best extension method overload 'ParralellEnumerable.Concat<CartridgeDTO>(ParalellQuery<CartridgeDTO>, IEnumerable<CartRidgeDTO>)' requires a reciever of type ParalellQuery<Cartridge>()

Comment: I'm sure that you'll be able to solve a build error. Take the time to understand _why_ it doesn't work.